# Real analysis Countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Stuck on this question,

Let $S$ be a non empty subset of the real line. Suppose there exists $c>0$ such that if $x,y \in S$ with $x \ne y$ then $|x- y|\ge c$. Show that $S$ is a countable set.

Comment: FYI, I rolled back your edit to preserve the original question, which has already been answered. Please don't edit an old question to ask a new one. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the intervals of the form $[kc,(k+1)c)$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. They partition $\mathbb R$ and there can be at most one element of $S$ in each one.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $I_a:=[-a,a]$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
Now let's show, first, that $S_a:=S\cap I_a$ is a finite set for all $a>0$
[The main idea is that the points of $S$ don't want to be too close each other, so an interval can't hold too many of them.]
Given that $\left|x-y\right|\geq c$ for distincts $x,y\in S$, we have that $B_a=\bigcup_{s\in S_a}[s-\frac{c}{2},s+\frac{c}{2}]\subseteq I_{a+c}$ and the family is disjoint, so $\lambda(B_a)=\sum_{s\in S_a}\lambda([s-\frac{c}{2},s+\frac{c}{2}])=\left|S_a\right|·c$ now it suffices to note that - by inclusion, $\lambda(B_a)\leq \lambda(I_{a+\frac{c}{2}})=2a+c$. So we have
$\left|S_a\right|\leq\frac{2a}{c}+1$.
To conclude we have that $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$ and, as countable union of (at most) finite sets it is (at most) countable.

Comment: Ok thanks and I know this looks right but honestly this doesn't make sense to me. Is there a short proof which makes sense.

Comment: Actually the answer from Jorge Fernandez is more simple and perfectly right, so better :)

Answer (score 0):

Now, a less elementary proof (but less ugly in my opinion). Take $K_n:=\left[-n,n\right]$, a compact interval for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Every $S_n=S\cap K_n$ is finite as (subset of a) discrete set in a compact space. Again $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$ is countable union of finite sets.

Comment: Ok for this why did you choose like [-n,n]? And there is no |x-y|>=c required to write here? Thanks!

Comment: Just because I was searching for an easy sequence of compact intervals who cover $\mathbb{R}$. The inequality is used in the word "discrete"